# Can anyone access pluggable-transports/meek.git?

Tags: tor

```
git clone https://git.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/meek.git
```

> fatal: unable to access 'https://git.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/meek.git/': Failed to connect to gitweb.torproject.org port 443: Connection timed out

and I get TorBrowser running ,and config git with

```
git config --global http.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'

git config --global https.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'
```

and git clone get these message:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://git.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/meek.git/': Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (1)

Does meek source code accessible?

I want use tor not JUST TorBrowser Bundle . and I need meek to get out the GFW .

> curl https://torproject.org --socks5 '127.0.0.1:9150'
>   curl: (7) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (6)

TorBrowser 6.0.6 is running 
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WlrB.png)

Comment: Worked fine for me.  Someone blocking gitweb.torproject.org for you maybe?  I can upload the clone of the git repo to another URL you might be able to DL from temporarily if that'd help.  Looks like a problem with the SOCKS proxy and Git, but you might try cloning http://dccbbv6cooddgcrq.onion/pluggable-transports/meek.git as well.

Comment: Thanks. Yes,the whole torproject.org domain has blodked .That's why i want to use TorBrowser's proxy to get around . But it does not work. The .onion domain does not work too."Could not resolve host: dccbbv6cooddgcrq.onion".I don't know why TBB's(TorBrowser Bundle)proxy does not work . Does git support socks5 proxy ? I found a gitub repository of meek,but it's 2years old . I neek build meek from source , but i cann't access the source code .

Comment: Does this has something to do with torrc's configuration ???  I use git protocal and get this error : ERROR: Got error response from SOCKS server: 5 (connection refused).
FATAL: failed to begin relaying via SOCKS.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.By default , TorBrowser refuse socks connection ??? The torrc (/opt/tor-browser_zh-CN/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc)only has meek bridge configuration , not like the /etc/tor/torrc

Comment: Get TBB running . Default proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:9150 and config git with git config --global https.proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:9150 ,then git clone https://git.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/meek.git get timeout error . but  git clone other github repository like https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d.git works fine . so , does this issus has something to do with torproject.org site ??? I cann't access it's source code ?

Comment: https://gitweb.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/meek.git/tree/ shows every directory's permission is d--------- no 'w' no 'x' no 'r' ,how can anybody clone the repository ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apparent problem is that Git's HTTP(S) proxy doesn't do DNS resolution over SOCKS and relies on your system DNS server.  So when you try to clone (via https://gitweb.torproject or the .onion site) it's doing a DNS lookup through your default DNS servers which I think are giving you bad information.

This should work (because it resolves DNS over Tor):

```
curl https://torproject.org --socks5-hostname '127.0.0.1:9150'
```

While this probably doesn't (because it uses your default DNS servers):

```
curl https://torproject.org --socks5 '127.0.0.1:9150'
```

That said, I didn't try very hard or look more into having Git's proxy resolve DNS over SOCKS, but the easier thing to do is try using `torsocks` or `proxychains`.

Go to https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng - download, configure, build, and install.  Then edit `/etc/proxychains.conf` and change `socks4 127.0.0.1 9050` to `socks5 127.0.0.1 9150`

Then run:

```
./proxychains4 git clone http://dccbbv6cooddgcrq.onion/pluggabletransports/meek.git
```

If it works, you're set.

The directory permissions are fine.  They show up funny in the web viewer `d---------` but when you clone it, the directories will get permissions  (probably 0755) based on your umask.

In any case, if you're still stuck, I've uploaded the meek git clone to https://drew.co.il/downloads/meek.zip so you can try to download that.  It'll have the `.git` directory in it in case you need that later.

Comment: Thanks @drew010 .It works fine ! You are awesome. But proxychains does need root access .And in Fedora it calls "proxychains-ng" . In case of anyone else need that information . Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I checked meek source tree ,and find out it has d--------- permission . There is no 'w',nor 'x' and no 'r' ,but yet ,the directory can be accessed from browser ,and its file has 644 permission . Perhaps that's why i cann't clone it .

**BTW**,TBB's proxy works fine . and git's proxy configuration also right . If anyone else wants to know .